Is there a way to convert the below nested lists to dataframe in R
Is there a way to convert the below nested lists to dataframe in R? The lists below are not equally sized so wanted to check if we can convert this is to dataframe. In case if the value is not present, it should be replaced by NA
Appreciate if anyone can help me here
df = list(profile = list(symbol = "GUJTHEM.BO", price = 327.15, beta = 0.74051946, 
                    volAvg = 28661, mktCap = 37012635091, lastDiv = 0.91667, 
                    range = "72.45-329.25", changes = 7.15, companyName = "Gujarat Themis Biosyn Limited", 
                    currency = "INR", cik = NULL, isin = "INE942C01045", cusip = NULL, 
                    exchange = "Bombay Stock Exchange", exchangeShortName = "BSE", 
                    industry = "Medical - Pharmaceuticals", website = "http://www.gtbl.in", 
                    description = "Gujarat Themis Biosyn Ltd. operates as a pharmaceutical company. The firm engages in the manufacture of drugs. Its products include Rifamycin and Lovastatin. The company was founded on December 11, 1981 and is headquartered in Mumbai, India.", 
                    ceo = "Tapas B. Guhathakurata", sector = "Healthcare", country = "IN", 
                    fullTimeEmployees = "109", phone = NULL, address = NULL, 
                    city = "Mumbai", state = NULL, zip = NULL, dcfDiff = 269.86597, 
                    dcf = 40.0840275267633, image = "https://images.financialmodelingprep.com/symbol/GUJTHEM.BO.png", 
                    ipoDate = "2002-01-02", defaultImage = FALSE, isEtf = FALSE, 
                    isActivelyTrading = TRUE, isAdr = FALSE, isFund = FALSE), 
     metrics = list(dividendYielTTM = 0.00280198685618218, volume = 65232, 
                    yearHigh = 329.25, yearLow = 72.45), ratios = list(list(
                        dividendYielTTM = 0.00280198685618218, dividendYielPercentageTTM = 0.280198685618218, 
                        peRatioTTM = 45.1462462181789, pegRatioTTM = -4.47304255293272, 
                        payoutRatioTTM = 0, currentRatioTTM = 2.52653313861836, 
                        quickRatioTTM = 2.30226114372479, cashRatioTTM = 0.405047437596108, 
                        daysOfSalesOutstandingTTM = 67.5415263243447, daysOfInventoryOutstandingTTM = 22.4513726790451, 
                        operatingCycleTTM = 89.9928990033898, daysOfPayablesOutstandingTTM = 61.5881830238727, 
                        cashConversionCycleTTM = 28.4047159795172, grossProfitMarginTTM = 0.511702623011759, 
                        operatingProfitMarginTTM = 0.46029151482928, pretaxProfitMarginTTM = 0.457815704653914, 
                        netProfitMarginTTM = 0.341295257363155, effectiveTaxRateTTM = 0.254512456643638, 
                        returnOnAssetsTTM = 0.212371777951953, returnOnEquityTTM = 0.262134869576203, 
                        returnOnCapitalEmployedTTM = 0.312455901495426, netIncomePerEBTTTM = 0.745486128793151, 
                        ebtPerEbitTTM = 0.994621212654149, ebitPerRevenueTTM = 0.46029151482928, 
                        debtRatioTTM = 0.0054941800135803, debtEquityRatioTTM = 0.00610190549162543, 
                        longTermDebtToCapitalizationTTM = 0.00498889599913074, 
                        totalDebtToCapitalizationTTM = 0.00606489805686609, interestCoverageTTM = 235.817850033179, 
                        cashFlowToDebtRatioTTM = 2.73155346926801, companyEquityMultiplierTTM = 1.11061258942062, 
                        receivablesTurnoverTTM = 5.40408278970798, payablesTurnoverTTM = 5.92646157232012, 
                        inventoryTurnoverTTM = 16.2573578559262, fixedAssetTurnoverTTM = 0.864508988056981, 
                        assetTurnoverTTM = 0.622252355900682, operatingCashFlowPerShareTTM = 0.512083835117145, 
                        freeCashFlowPerShareTTM = 0.512083835117145, cashPerShareTTM = 2.49001830463895, 
                        operatingCashFlowSalesRatioTTM = 0.0241182638114006, 
                        freeCashFlowOperatingCashFlowRatioTTM = 1, cashFlowCoverageRatiosTTM = 2.73155346926801, 
                        shortTermCoverageRatiosTTM = 15.3196215549157, capitalExpenditureCoverageRatioTTM = 0, 
                        dividendPaidAndCapexCoverageRatioTTM = 0, priceBookValueRatioTTM = 10.6483186985541, 
                        priceToBookRatioTTM = 10.6483186985541, priceToSalesRatioTTM = 23.9697249739499, 
                        priceEarningsRatioTTM = 45.1462462181789, priceToFreeCashFlowsRatioTTM = 993.841230089684, 
                        priceToOperatingCashFlowsRatioTTM = 638.860236478975, 
                        priceCashFlowRatioTTM = 638.860236478975, priceEarningsToGrowthRatioTTM = -4.47304255293272, 
                        priceSalesRatioTTM = 23.9697249739499, enterpriseValueMultipleTTM = 50.651759310777, 
                        priceFairValueTTM = 10.6483186985541, dividendPerShareTTM = 0.91667)), 
     insideTrades = list(), keyExecutives = list(), splitsHistory = list(
         list(date = "2024-08-09", label = "August 09, 24", numerator = 3, 
              denominator = 2), list(date = "2023-10-10", label = "October 10, 23", 
                                     numerator = 5, denominator = 1)), stockDividend = list(
                                         list(date = "2024-07-15", label = "July 15, 24", adjDividend = 0.16667, 
                                              dividend = 0.25, recordDate = "2024-07-15", paymentDate = "2024-08-22", 
                                              declarationDate = ""), list(date = "2024-02-22", 
                                                                          label = "February 22, 24", adjDividend = 0.75, dividend = 0.75, 
                                                                          recordDate = "", paymentDate = "", declarationDate = ""), 
                                         list(date = "2023-09-01", label = "September 01, 23", 
                                              adjDividend = 0.2, dividend = 1, recordDate = "2023-09-01", 
                                              paymentDate = "2023-10-09", declarationDate = ""), 
                                         list(date = "2022-12-02", label = "December 02, 22", 
                                              adjDividend = 0.88, dividend = 4.4, recordDate = "2022-12-02", 
                                              paymentDate = "2022-12-21", declarationDate = ""), 
                                         list(date = "2022-08-29", label = "August 29, 22", adjDividend = 0.8, 
                                              dividend = 4, recordDate = "2022-08-30", paymentDate = "2022-10-07", 
                                              declarationDate = "")), stockNews = list(), rating = list(
                                                  list(symbol = "GUJTHEM.BO", date = "2024-11-08", rating = "B+", 
                                                       ratingScore = 3, ratingRecommendation = "Neutral", 
                                                       ratingDetailsDCFScore = 3, ratingDetailsDCFRecommendation = "Neutral", 
                                                       ratingDetailsROEScore = 5, ratingDetailsROERecommendation = "Strong Buy", 
                                                       ratingDetailsROAScore = 5, ratingDetailsROARecommendation = "Strong Buy", 
                                                       ratingDetailsDEScore = 4, ratingDetailsDERecommendation = "Buy", 
                                                       ratingDetailsPEScore = 1, ratingDetailsPERecommendation = "Strong Sell", 
                                                       ratingDetailsPBScore = 1, ratingDetailsPBRecommendation = "Strong Sell")), 
     financialsAnnual = list(income = list(list(date = "2024-03-31", 
                                                symbol = "GUJTHEM.BO", reportedCurrency = "INR", cik = "0000000000", 
                                                fillingDate = "2024-03-31", acceptedDate = "2024-03-29 20:00:00", 
                                                calendarYear = "2023", period = "FY", revenue = 1698219000, 
                                                costOfRevenue = 818880000, grossProfit = 879339000, grossProfitRatio = 0.5178007077, 
                                                researchAndDevelopmentExpenses = 38925000, generalAndAdministrativeExpenses = 13933000, 
                                                sellingAndMarketingExpenses = 3622000, sellingGeneralAndAdministrativeExpenses = 127360000, 
                                                otherExpenses = 43657000, operatingExpenses = 127360000, 
                                                costAndExpenses = 946240000, interestIncome = 40351000, 
                                                interestExpense = 2292000, depreciationAndAmortization = 35359000, 
                                                ebitda = 787338000, ebitdaratio = 0.4636257161, operatingIncome = 751979000, 
                                                operatingIncomeRatio = 0.4428044911, totalOtherIncomeExpensesNet = 41364000, 
                                                incomeBeforeTax = 793343000, incomeBeforeTaxRatio = 0.4671617736, 
                                                incomeTaxExpense = 201711000, netIncome = 591632000, 
                                                netIncomeRatio = 0.3483838068, eps = 8.14, epsdiluted = 8.14, 
                                                weightedAverageShsOut = 72682072, weightedAverageShsOutDil = 72643510, 
                                                link = "", finalLink = ""), list(date = "2023-03-31", 
                                                                                 symbol = "GUJTHEM.BO", reportedCurrency = "INR", cik = "0000000000", 
                                                                                 fillingDate = "2023-03-31", acceptedDate = "2023-03-30 20:00:00", 
                                                                                 calendarYear = "2022", period = "FY", revenue = 1489729000, 
                                                                                 costOfRevenue = 307810000, grossProfit = 1181919000, 
                                                                                 grossProfitRatio = 0.7933785272, researchAndDevelopmentExpenses = 29324000, 
                                                                                 generalAndAdministrativeExpenses = 14405000, sellingAndMarketingExpenses = 10075000, 
                                                                                 sellingGeneralAndAdministrativeExpenses = 37726000, otherExpenses = 60238000, 
                                                                                 operatingExpenses = 465500000, costAndExpenses = 773310000, 
                                                                                 interestIncome = 50444000, interestExpense = 2007000, 
                                                                                 depreciationAndAmortization = 25757000, ebitda = 802412000, 
                                                                                 ebitdaratio = 0.5386295091, operatingIncome = 802411742, 
                                                                                 operatingIncomeRatio = 0.5386293359, totalOtherIncomeExpensesNet = -27763742.4299999, 
                                                                                 incomeBeforeTax = 774648000, incomeBeforeTaxRatio = 0.5199925624, 
                                                                                 incomeTaxExpense = 194960000, netIncome = 579688000, 
                                                                                 netIncomeRatio = 0.3891231224, eps = 7.98, epsdiluted = 7.98, 
                                                                                 weightedAverageShsOut = 72643516, weightedAverageShsOutDil = 72643510, 
                                                                                 link = "", finalLink = ""), list(date = "2022-03-31", 
                                                                                                                  symbol = "GUJTHEM.BO", reportedCurrency = "INR", cik = "0000000000", 
                                                                                                                  fillingDate = "2022-03-31", acceptedDate = "2022-03-30 20:00:00", 
                                                                                                                  calendarYear = "2021", period = "FY", revenue = 1141917000, 
                                                                                                                  costOfRevenue = 208921000, grossProfit = 932996000, grossProfitRatio = 0.8170436205, 
                                                                                                                  researchAndDevelopmentExpenses = 4500000, generalAndAdministrativeExpenses = 8279000, 
                                                                                                                  sellingAndMarketingExpenses = 2924000, sellingGeneralAndAdministrativeExpenses = 11203000, 
                                                                                                                  otherExpenses = 713000, operatingExpenses = 367252000, 
                                                                                                                  costAndExpenses = 576173000, interestIncome = 32610000, 
                                                                                                                  interestExpense = 7328000, depreciationAndAmortization = 22330000, 
                                                                                                                  ebitda = 620541000, ebitdaratio = 0.5434204062, operatingIncome = 598211000, 
                                                                                                                  operatingIncomeRatio = 0.5238655699, totalOtherIncomeExpensesNet = -7866000, 
                                                                                                                  incomeBeforeTax = 590345000, incomeBeforeTaxRatio = 0.5169771533, 
                                                                                                                  incomeTaxExpense = 154103000, netIncome = 436242000, 
                                                                                                                  netIncomeRatio = 0.3820260141, eps = 6.01, epsdiluted = 6.01, 
                                                                                                                  weightedAverageShsOut = 72643521, weightedAverageShsOutDil = 72643510, 
                                                                                                                  link = "", finalLink = ""), list(date = "2021-03-31", 
                                                                                                                                                   symbol = "GUJTHEM.BO", reportedCurrency = "INR", cik = "0000000000", 
                                                                                                                                                   fillingDate = "2021-03-31", acceptedDate = "2021-03-30 20:00:00", 
                                                                                                                                                   calendarYear = "2020", period = "FY", revenue = 904250000, 
                                                                                                                                                   costOfRevenue = 211075000, grossProfit = 693175000, grossProfitRatio = 0.7665745093, 
                                                                                                                                                   researchAndDevelopmentExpenses = 0, generalAndAdministrativeExpenses = 6609000, 
                                                                                                                                                   sellingAndMarketingExpenses = 1924000, sellingGeneralAndAdministrativeExpenses = 8533000, 
                                                                                                                                                   otherExpenses = 1590000, operatingExpenses = 297682000, 
                                                                                                                                                   costAndExpenses = 508757000, interestIncome = 21509000, 
                                                                                                                                                   interestExpense = 7895000, depreciationAndAmortization = 17325000, 
                                                                                                                                                   ebitda = 433983000, ebitdaratio = 0.4799369643, operatingIncome = 416658000, 
                                                                                                                                                   operatingIncomeRatio = 0.4607774399, totalOtherIncomeExpensesNet = -7839000, 
                                                                                                                                                   incomeBeforeTax = 408819000, incomeBeforeTaxRatio = 0.4521083771, 
                                                                                                                                                   incomeTaxExpense = 107023000, netIncome = 301797000, 
                                                                                                                                                   netIncomeRatio = 0.3337539397, eps = 4.15, epsdiluted = 4.15, 
                                                                                                                                                   weightedAverageShsOut = 72652142, weightedAverageShsOutDil = 72643510, 
                                                                                                                                                   link = "", finalLink = ""), list(date = "2020-03-31", 
                                                                                                                                                                                    symbol = "GUJTHEM.BO", reportedCurrency = "INR", cik = "0000000000", 
                                                                                                                                                                                    fillingDate = "2020-03-31", acceptedDate = "2020-03-30 20:00:00", 
                                                                                                                                                                                    calendarYear = "2019", period = "FY", revenue = 849769000, 
                                                                                                                                                                                    costOfRevenue = 154691000, grossProfit = 695078000, grossProfitRatio = 0.8179611165, 
                                                                                                                                                                                    researchAndDevelopmentExpenses = 0, generalAndAdministrativeExpenses = 4904000, 
                                                                                                                                                                                    sellingAndMarketingExpenses = 5062000, sellingGeneralAndAdministrativeExpenses = 9966000, 
                                                                                                                                                                                    otherExpenses = 1142000, operatingExpenses = 389782000, 
                                                                                                                                                                                    costAndExpenses = 544473000, interestIncome = 15714000, 
                                                                                                                                                                                    interestExpense = 8572000, depreciationAndAmortization = 13620000, 
                                                                                                                                                                                    ebitda = 335110000, ebitdaratio = 0.3943542304, operatingIncome = 321490000, 
                                                                                                                                                                                    operatingIncomeRatio = 0.3783263452, totalOtherIncomeExpensesNet = -8924000, 
                                                                                                                                                                                    incomeBeforeTax = 312566000, incomeBeforeTaxRatio = 0.3678246676, 
                                                                                                                                                                                    incomeTaxExpense = 75820000, netIncome = 236746000, netIncomeRatio = 0.2786004196, 
                                                                                                                                                                                    eps = 3.26, epsdiluted = 3.26, weightedAverageShsOut = 72643510, 
                                                                                                                                                                                    weightedAverageShsOutDil = 72643510, link = "", finalLink = "")), 
                             balance = list(list(date = "2024-03-31", symbol = "GUJTHEM.BO", 
                                                 reportedCurrency = "INR", cik = "0000000000", fillingDate = "2024-03-31", 
                                                 acceptedDate = "2024-03-29 20:00:00", calendarYear = "2023", 
                                                 period = "FY", cashAndCashEquivalents = 81568000, 
                                                 shortTermInvestments = 98663000, cashAndShortTermInvestments = 81568000, 
                                                 netReceivables = 270278000, inventory = 33268000, 
                                                 otherCurrentAssets = 90507000, totalCurrentAssets = 475621000, 
                                                 propertyPlantEquipmentNet = 1292399000, goodwill = 0, 
                                                 intangibleAssets = 0, goodwillAndIntangibleAssets = 0, 
                                                 longTermInvestments = 351394000, taxAssets = 0, otherNonCurrentAssets = 91718999, 
                                                 totalNonCurrentAssets = 1735511999, otherAssets = 1, 
                                                 totalAssets = 2211133000, accountPayables = 99084000, 
                                                 shortTermDebt = 15437000, taxPayables = 0, deferredRevenue = 0, 
                                                 otherCurrentLiabilities = 47071000, totalCurrentLiabilities = 161592000, 
                                                 longTermDebt = 12247000, deferredRevenueNonCurrent = 0, 
                                                 deferredTaxLiabilitiesNonCurrent = 16643999, otherNonCurrentLiabilities = 6890000, 
                                                 totalNonCurrentLiabilities = 35780999, otherLiabilities = 1, 
                                                 capitalLeaseObligations = 12247000, totalLiabilities = 197373000, 
                                                 preferredStock = 0, commonStock = 72644000, retainedEarnings = 1917904000, 
                                                 accumulatedOtherComprehensiveIncomeLoss = 1569000, 
                                                 othertotalStockholdersEquity = 21643000, totalStockholdersEquity = 2013760000, 
                                                 totalEquity = 2013760000, totalLiabilitiesAndStockholdersEquity = 2211133000, 
                                                 minorityInterest = 0, totalLiabilitiesAndTotalEquity = 2211133000, 
                                                 totalInvestments = 351394000, totalDebt = 27684000, 
                                                 netDebt = -53884000, link = "", finalLink = ""), 
                                            list(date = "2023-03-31", symbol = "GUJTHEM.BO", 
                                                 reportedCurrency = "INR", cik = "0000000000", 
                                                 fillingDate = "2023-03-31", acceptedDate = "2023-03-30 20:00:00", 
                                                 calendarYear = "2022", period = "FY", cashAndCashEquivalents = 60550000, 
                                                 shortTermInvestments = 41762000, cashAndShortTermInvestments = 102312000, 
                                                 netReceivables = 354053000, inventory = 146188000, 
                                                 otherCurrentAssets = 5912000, totalCurrentAssets = 608465000, 
                                                 propertyPlantEquipmentNet = 532557000, goodwill = 0, 
                                                 intangibleAssets = 0, goodwillAndIntangibleAssets = 0, 
                                                 longTermInvestments = 373566000, taxAssets = 0, 
                                                 otherNonCurrentAssets = 148693000, totalNonCurrentAssets = 1054816000, 
                                                 otherAssets = 0, totalAssets = 1663281000, accountPayables = 95445000, 
                                                 shortTermDebt = 4191000, taxPayables = 5280000, 
                                                 deferredRevenue = 37897000, otherCurrentLiabilities = 15249000, 
                                                 totalCurrentLiabilities = 152782000, longTermDebt = 0, 
                                                 deferredRevenueNonCurrent = 0, deferredTaxLiabilitiesNonCurrent = 1.3e+07, 
                                                 otherNonCurrentLiabilities = 6040000, totalNonCurrentLiabilities = 19040000, 
                                                 otherLiabilities = 0, capitalLeaseObligations = 4191000, 
                                                 totalLiabilities = 171822000, preferredStock = 0, 
                                                 commonStock = 72644000, retainedEarnings = 1395602000, 
                                                 accumulatedOtherComprehensiveIncomeLoss = 1569000, 
                                                 othertotalStockholdersEquity = 21644000, totalStockholdersEquity = 1491459000, 
                                                 totalEquity = 1491459000, totalLiabilitiesAndStockholdersEquity = 1663281000, 
                                                 minorityInterest = 0, totalLiabilitiesAndTotalEquity = 1663281000, 
                                                 totalInvestments = 415328000, totalDebt = 4191000, 
                                                 netDebt = -56359000, link = "", finalLink = ""))))

I tried with below approach but it is failing
nullToNA <- function(x) {
  x[sapply(x, is.null)] <- NA
  return(x)
}

df_1 = as.data.frame(rbindlist(lapply(df, nullToNA), fill = TRUE))
Error in x[sapply(x, is.null)] <- NA : invalid subscript type 'list'


Can you create a simplified version of the data and the desired output? It's not clear what the output dimensions should be. Mabye pick just one of your list. df[[10]] might work since it has some uneven components

Maybe collapse::unlist2d()?

You could rewrite your function slightly and use it in rapply with how='unlist' (default).
> nullToNA <- function(x) if (is.null(x) || length(x) == 0) NA else x
> 
> res <- rapply(df, nullToNA) |> t() |> as.data.frame() |> 
+   type.convert(as.is=TRUE)
> 
> dim(res)
[1]   1 449
> res[, 1:10]
  profile.symbol profile.price profile.beta profile.volAvg profile.mktCap profile.lastDiv profile.range profile.changes
1     GUJTHEM.BO        327.15    0.7405195          28661    37012635091         0.91667  72.45-329.25            7.15
            profile.companyName profile.currency
1 Gujarat Themis Biosyn Limited              INR


|> is not working in my case :)

@rakshuvin You are likely on an old R version. R 4.1 introduced the native pipe |>

got it thanks..

@rakshuvin I should have mentioned: if you can't update your R version. You can use the magrittr library pipe %>%

They can also do type.convert(as.data.frame(t(rapply(df, nullToNA))), as.is=TRUE) w/o pipe @gabagool

I'm not 100% sure what your desired output was, but I did my best! I generally prefer purrr for mapping function over the apply family. I also used @jay.sf's nullToNA function.
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
library(purrr)

nullToNA <- function(x) {
  if (is.null(x) || length(x) == 0)
    NA
  else
    x
}

# recursively: 
# check if input is all atomic
# if so, return as data.table
# if not, apply to each element of the input and then data.table::rbindlist to convert to data.table
rec_as.data.table <- function(l) {
  if (all(map_lgl(l, is.atomic))) {
    as.data.table(l)
  } else{
    map(l, rec_as.data.table) %>%
      rbindlist(fill = TRUE, use.names = TRUE)
  }
}

df_clean <-
  df %>%
  keep(\(l) length(l) != 0) %>% # remove elements like insideTrades that is just an empty list
  map(\(el) map(el, nullToNA)) %>% # convert NULL to NA
  map(rec_as.data.table) %>% # convert each element to data.table
  rbindlist(use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE) # now row bind all of the data.tables

I would personally not have the last step rbindlist(use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE), since it results in a data.table with 199 columns, and many elements are NA. I'd prefer to just have a list as the final output, but I wasn't sure what you wanted.
Sample of final output:
> head(df_clean[, 1:5])
       symbol  price      beta volAvg      mktCap
       <char>  <num>     <num>  <num>       <num>
1: GUJTHEM.BO 327.15 0.7405195  28661 37012635091
2:       <NA>     NA        NA     NA          NA
3:       <NA>     NA        NA     NA          NA
4:       <NA>     NA        NA     NA          NA
5:       <NA>     NA        NA     NA          NA
6:       <NA>     NA        NA     NA          NA


library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  compact() %>% 
  map(compact) %>% 
  map(as.data.frame) %>% 
  bind_rows()


Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.
